# paradox behavior: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode ...: invalid start byte - works in IDLE3, Spyder but not Sublime 3 (Mac OSX)

Tags: unicode, sublimetext3, spyder, python-idle

I got a weird error, or better to say behavior. 
This is the error message: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9f in position 8: invalid start byte"

I get this in Sublime 3 with the Python build system using this version:

3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 26 2018, 08:42:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]

I do not get this error with the exact same code in the IDLE3 or wit Spyder using the SAME version:

3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 26 2018, 08:42:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

(Btw, I get this error with this line of code: text = str(pyperclip.paste()) using text in the only containing a phone number and text.)

Comment: The error means that \x9F is an invalid start byte. In other words, the string you're trying to translate is not UTF-8. The other utilities probably output a \uFFFD for the bad sequence instead of throwing an error.

Comment: What do you mean by utilities? I thought it gets interpreter / executed by Python and there I was wondering why I was getting different results in different setting with the same Python interpreter?